# What speed will I end up connecting old ADSL(54Mbps) router with new AP/Client Router(300Mbps)?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router

I am busy using an old 54Mbps TP-Link ADSL(phone jack connected) router to network all my home computers. I have recently been given a new 300Mbps TP-Link AP/Client Router (ethernet cable connection)....

If I had to connect the 2 using an ethernet cable, would I get an increase Mbps speed or will it be capped at the lowest 54Mpbs current speed...?

I'm presuming it will be as fast as the slowest modem.... but I have no idea...

Any comments on this would be appreciated...

Comment: I do not think this deserves an answer longer than this, but ALWAYS in networking the speed between two host is determined by the slowest (phy layer)

Answer (score 2):

The 54Mbps and 300Mbps are the maximum speed possible over WLAN, your speed over DSL will differ.

So if you are copying files between two computers connected to the same WLAN, you will notice a performance gain when using 300Mbps WLAN. When downloading from Internet, you will be limited to your ADSL speed.

Comment: Ok... thanx... so basically, my internet speed will be the same but transferring files between computers on the WAN will be better if I hook the 300Mbps router up... it's beginning to make sense... thanx

Answer (score 0):

#### What speed will I end up if I connect an ADSL (54 Mbps) router with a AP/Client Router (300 Mbps)?

It will be:

1. As fast as the slowest modem.
2. As fast as your internet at any point in time (if your internet is slower than your slowest modem).

However, I would be surprised if your ADSL internet is giving you 54 Mbps.

ADSL is normally limited to 8 Mbps and ADSL2+ to 24 Mbps assuming you are right next to the telephone exchange.

[image]

See [ADSL standards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ADSL#ADSL_standards) for more information.

Source [Chart of ADSL and ADSL2+ Speed Versus Distance](http://www.increasebroadbandspeed.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2012/01/ADSL-adsl2-speed-against-distance.png)

Comment: Thanx David... I have a 4Mbps ADSL connection but it usually hangs around 1.45Mbps (download speed)... so that will be the same... Cheers

Answer (score -1):

> If I had to connect the 2 using an ethernet cable, would I get an increase Mbps speed or will it be capped at the lowest 54Mpbs current speed...?

Take care with such setups on consumer hardware. It is possible to connect multiple NIC from a device or multiple ports from a network device (router/switch) to another router/switch. But the hardware has to support that.

If you are interested in that, you can read that wikipedia article about [Link aggregation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_aggregation).

> I'm presuming it will be as fast as the slowest modem.... but I have no idea...

That is correct. I don't like the term modem here, but assume we're talking about the same.

*In general, always check what channel (line) is the slowest in your path/network setup.*

There will be always a bottleneck along the path. Just find where that is.

Comment: The OP makes no mention of having two internet connections to bond.

Comment: Was thought as a example for link aggregation - deleted.